# php get value of array by unknown index in one statement

Tags: php, arrays, performance

if one is uncertain whether an array index exists, he normally does something like

```
if (isset($array[$key]))
    $val = $array[$key];
```

for large arrays, is it faster to not do this look up two times?

If yes, how would one go about doing this in one look up?

Comment: `$val = $array[$key] ?? null;`?

Comment: @Jeto doesnt that throw an error if key does not exist?

Comment: It does not: https://3v4l.org/572Zk. See [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce).

Comment: @Jeto looks like you have an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [null-coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce):

```
$val = $array[$key] ?? null;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
$val = isset($array[$key]) ? $array['key'] : null;
```

The only minor difference is that `$val` gets defined no matter what (to `null`), where in your original code it would stay undefined if you don't have an `else`.

I can't say for sure that it executes faster, but it's definitely handier/cleaner to write/maintain (since you don't write the same `$array[$key]` part twice within the statement).

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/mtG7S**